# Firebase database query and pagination at same time?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase database like this :

```
{ 
  "employers" : {
    "ibrahim" : {
      "id" : "ibrahim",
      "isManager" : 0,
      "mobile" : "010156055653",
      "name" : "ibrahim",
      "password" : "123456789",
      "rule" : 1,
      "username" : "ibrahim"
    } 
  }, "orders" : {
    "-M1p0fCFjYWq33KAlmX-" : {
      "c_id" : "-M1RzUy70Sc2zeTrf1Mr",
      "c_name" : "jtyjyt",
      "createdDate" : 1583585078758,
      "deviceId" : "fwefdewfewf",
      "e_id" : "ibrahim",
      "endDate" : 0,
      "finished" : false,
      "message" : "",
      "startDate" : 0,
      "started" : false,
      "t_date" : 1583585040000,
      "taskDetails" : "ewffewf",
      "task_id" : "-M1p0fCFjYWq33KAlmX-",
      "task_type_id" : "erwfew"
    }
  }
}
```

I need to retrieves orders created employer has rule > 1 and do pagination at same time,
now i can't do same at one query because orderbyquery  can be used on one child

Comment: Please explain properly what data you want to retrieve user or orders ?

Comment: I need to retrieve orders based on employer rule

Comment: What have you tried so far in code?

Comment: I have tried to make the orders child of rule but this is not good option if i want to get one order